# Screen brightness for hp probook 4540s doesnt work?

Tags: dual-boot, brightness

I have applied

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Code:
If you change this file, run `update-grub` afterwards to update

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.
For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR= lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close gedit, next:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

And nothing changed I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 amd 64
Help !

Comment: If anything else does not work, you should use [Brightness Controller](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/).

Comment: i used and its not good it is like you you just gray out the colors but didn't reduce the brightness with that software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was stumped by this one also, but all you have to do is add the `acpi_backlight=vendor`

here:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

http://www.techjail.net/solved-brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin.html